# Select lines by poly using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location

I have a set of polys for cities and a set of lines for streets. What I'd like to do is anywhere a line segment (streets) is within a city (poly) have the value for the city applied to the line segment for example Wall St runs through City of NY but might also extend into the next city. I'd like the segments in NY to reflect NY the segments in the next city to reflect as such.

I've connected the poly and line features to ModelBuilder, created a new feature using "make feature" tool for both polys and lines. I've then fed the lines and polys into the Select Layer By Location tool. I run the model and get nothing? The model runs correctly The location is output is good (gdb I created) it's results are blank? I did refresh the gdb within ArcCatalog and still nothing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Intersect streets with polygons and color them by town

Answer (score 1):

The Select Layer by Location tool by itself will not change the data. It sounds like the Union (analysis) tool may be more appropriate. It will assign the attributes of the city to each street segment, and break the streets at city boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the spatial join tool.  This will output a file for you.  You will need to specify the join type for the attributes to get the results you are looking for.  As Bjorn said, a union will also work but will break the lines anywhere they cross a polygon boundary and also anywhere they cross another line.